# Removing trailing slash from redirected URLs (.jpg/ .htm/ .gif/) with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

I have a website that is being redirected from an old host.
I don't have the ability to change the redirect of the old host.

The issue is that the redirect is appending a trailing slash when it's not appropriate. Example: `http://example.com/picture.jpg/` or `http://example.com/page.html/`.

That is causing my server to return a 404.

Ideally, I would fix the redirect from the old site but cannot.

Is there a way to remove the trailing slash at the end of the URL?  This is a site that is not complex (straight simple html, no scripting languages, etc.).

I looked and couldn't find an existing solution.

Comment: Where are you using these directives? `.htaccess`? server config? `<Directory>` container? Are the requested URLs always a single path depth, as in your examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following to remove the trailing slash from any URL that ends with a file extension (`.jpg`, `.html`, `.png`, etc.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?\.[a-z]{2,4})/$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) only once you have tested that it works OK (avoid caching issues).

> **UPDATE:** http redirected to https, and https rewrote the funny trailing slash.

If these links are all in-bound to HTTP only (not HTTPS) then it would make sense to perform this redirect only in the HTTP vHost instead and redirect straight to HTTPS as well. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+?\.[a-z]{2,4})/$ https://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

(Although granted, if it is in the vHost for HTTPS then it will catch all requests.)

Comment: This was the answer, though it was SLIGHTLY more complicated.
I was using this within the VirtualHost definitions, and I was also redirecting http to https (which was working fine).    I added the above lines to the SSL/443 VirtualHost information and it took right away.    I have the https and http for this site configured in separate files.    So, I added it strictly to the https configuration file and it worked great.  http redirected to https, and https rewrote the funny trailing slash.    
Thank you so much!

Comment: If the links are inbound to the HTTP version only then it would perhaps make sense to include this redirect in the HTTP vHost instead - and redirect to HTTPS at the same time? One less redirect. (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: In this case, I can't **assume** they'd only be http, but it makes sense in the http rewrite rules to do both at the same time.   So I put the single rewrite rule in the http configuration file and put the simpler, original rule in the https config.   Thank you for all of your help!